# Nodejs Mongoose Bcrypt when i change hash password i cant login back

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

When i renew password I cant login back. giving response password is not match error but if I dont renew my password I can login.

Step 1 (Register)

```js
  Customer.findOne({$or:[{email:user.email},{username:user.username}]},function(err,data){
    if(!data){
      var tokencreator = generateUUID();
      var customer = new Customer({
        userid:uuidv4(),
        username:req.body.username,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:hashpass(req.body.password),
        token:tokencreator,
        registerdate:new Date(),
        lastlogin:new Date()
      })
   customer.save()
```

**Database** You can see work register.

[image]

Step 2 (Renew Password)

```js
app.post('/passnewer', function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body)
  Customer.findOne({passtoken:req.body.token},function(err,data){
    if(data){
      if(req.body.password != data.username){
        if(req.body.password = comparepass(req.body.password,data.password)){
          res.send({"Success":"Your New Password Cannot Be The Same As Your Old Password!","redirect":"false"});
        }
        else{
          Customer.findOne({passtoken:req.body.token},function(err,data){
          data.password = hashpass(req.body.password);
          data.save();
          });
          res.send({"Success":"Password Renewal Successful You Are Redirected!","redirect":"true"});
        }
      }
      else{
        res.send({"Success":"Your password cannot be the as your username!","redirect":"false"});
      }
    }
    else{
      res.send({"Denied":"İnvalid token!"});
    }
  })
})
```

**Response** You can see database password changed.

[image]

**Database**

[image]

Step 3 (Login Account) when I try to log in, it gives error.

```
app.post('/userlogin', function(req,res){
  Customer.findOne({email:req.body.email},function(err,data){
        if(data){
      if(data.password = comparepass(req.body.password,data.password)){
        if(data.status != "Active"){
          res.send({"Success":"Email verification need!"})
        }
        else{
          req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
          req.session.userID = data.userid;
          Customer.findOne({userid:req.session.userID},function(err,data){
          data.lastlogin = new Date();
          data.save()
          });
          res.send({"Success":"Login Success","redirect":"true"});
        }
            }else{
        res.send({"Success":"Password error!"});
            }
      }else{
        res.send({"Success":"E-Mail error!"});
        }
    });
})
```

**Response**

[image]

**Schema** My schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var customerSchema = new Schema({
    userid:String,
    username:String,
    email:String,
    password:String,
    address:String,
    registerdate:String,
    tickets:Array,
    token:String,
    passtoken:String,
    status: {
        type: String, 
        enum: ['Pending', 'Active'],
        default: 'Pending'
      },
      lastlogin:{
        type: String, 
        default: 'TBD'
      },
})

var Customer = mongoose.model('Customer',customerSchema)

module.exports = Customer
```

**hash and compare functions** Bcrypt functions

```
function hashpass(passnohash){
  return bcrypt.hashSync(`${hashprefix}${passnohash}`, saltRounds)
}

function comparepass(passnohash, passhash){
  return bcrypt.compareSync(`${hashprefix}${passnohash}`, passhash)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would `console.log` the new password hash getting saved to the database and then `console.log` the hash when you try to log back in (in step 3). See whether they're the same or not.

Then have a look at these lines in particular:

1. In POST `/userlogin` request handler:

   ```
   if(data.password = comparepass(req.body.password,data.password)){
   ```
2. In POST `/passnewer` request handler:

   ```
   if(req.body.password = comparepass(req.body.password,data.password)){
   ```

Both of the above lines make assignments (not comparisons). So it seems like you overwrite the password with the return value of `comparepass` (`comparepass` seems to return a `boolean`).

This may be a potential bug (if I'm reading things correctly), since `req.body.password` seems to get overwritten  with `true`/`false`, meaning you save the hash of `true`/`false` (and not the hash of the user's new password) when you call `data.save()`.

(If `comparepassword` returns a `boolean`, you can use its return value directly within the `if` statement. No need to compare it to `data.password` or `req.body.password`.)

Answer (score 1):

In route `POST /passnewer' you overwrite` req.body.password`by`if(req.body.password = comparepass(req.body.password,data.password))`

Now your new password will become `true` (or `false`), then you hash and save this password to your record in the database.

```
if(comparepass(req.body.password,data.password))
```

That enough, why you always assign a variable in if condition?